# Como hacer mas rápida la función glob() en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, foreach

tengo un host local con millones de imágenes, estoy haciendo una aplicación con php que manda llamar las imágenes del directorio donde se encuentran alojadas con GLOB(), si funciona pero tarda demasiado en recuperar las imágenes, ¿Como lo puedo hacer mas rápido?. Dejo el código abajo.

```
<?php
     $dir = "//168.10.10.12/mdc/imagenes/00232431.*.jpg";
     foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
        echo "$file<br>";                   
     }
?>
```

Comment: Supongo que cuando hablas de millones exageras. En cualquier caso creo que llegado a ese punto lo recomendable seria crear una base de datos en lugar de leer el directorio directamente.

Comment: El directorio contiene mas de 3 500 000, pero preguntaba porque ya realizaban esta acción(buscar desde directorio) pero con visual, solo que la realizo actualmente con php, ya que no tengo acceso al código de visual.

Comment: El fin último cual es? Listar todos los archivos? O saber si un determinado archivo existe dentro del directorio?  Lo pregunto por la otra pregunta que has realizado y son enfoques diferentes.

Comment: pues saber si el archivo existe y que lo traiga con sus coincidencias, el glob lo realiza muy bien pero no es tan rapido

Comment: Y por qué no una solución más similar a lo que te puse en la la otra pregunta. Es decir preguntar si el archivo existe en el directorio directamente, en lugar de recorrer todos los archivos y si existe lo puedes recuperar. Y hacer lo que corresponda, pero un bucle de 3.5M de iteraciones no creo que sea lo más óptimo.

Comment: si, estuve revisando lo que me contestaste y si, ya seria solo hacer unas adecuaciones, pero exactamente es lo que quiero, muchas gracias.